# Async task crashes the aplication on android when internet is unavailable

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, okhttp

In my android app I've used a async task to handle my internet request. I achieved that by using the [okhttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), which makes it easy to make internet requests. I have a lot of the code surrounded my try/catch statements, but they somehow do not trigger when there is an unhandled exception so the app crashes. That only happens when the internet is disconnected or is slow in areas.

I've looked for similar posts, but found out that people who had the same problems didn't try/catch, so the exceptions weren't handled
I've also tried to make a checker for the internet accessibility, but that didn't work out too well, because i would much rather do it with clean try-catching.

```
private class prenesi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String odgovor = null;
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody vsebina = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("kraj", params[0])
                .build();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://mypage.com/login.php")
                .post(vsebina)
                .build();

        Response response = null;

        try
        {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!response.isSuccessful())
        {
            odgovor = "Napaka.";
        }
        else
            try
            {
                odgovor = response.body().string();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return odgovor;
    }
}
```

The devconsole says the problem is in the doInBackground() and i guess it caused because the null pointer exception, though I'm not entirely sure what that means:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Could somebody point me towards the flaw please. I'm stuck with this.
All the help will be very appreciated, hope to solve this problem soon.
Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Try using the debugger and see the point where your app crashes. Or, you can try using logs to check for the point of crash.

Comment: What that function do?
`response = client.newCall(request).execute();`

Comment: it makes a request to the web. it is try-catched tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to initialize your `String` value. Run it by first setting `String odgovor="";` instead of `String odgovor= null;`

Try modifying the code to this

```
String odgovor="";
try{ 
response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
odgovor = "Napaka.";
} else{
odgovor = response.body().string();
}} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem in the end was with the isSuccessul method, which was a bit cheesy, idk why, but instead of it i used if(response == null).